# How to add separate vendor scripts to different pages in multi-page Webpack project?

Tags: webpack

I got multiple entry points in my config:

```
entry: {
 'main': './src/main.js',
 'page.a': './src/page.a.js',
 'page.b': './src/page.b.js'
}
```

There is some imports from */node_modules/* in each file.

Vendor scripts compiled separately using SplitChunks:

```
splitChunks: {
 cacheGroups: {
  vendor: {
   test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*\.js$/,
   chunks: 'all'
  }
 }
}
```

So in my build I have

- main.js
- page.a.js
- page.b.js
- vendor~main.js
- vendor~page.a.js
- vendor~page.b.js

HTML pages compile as follows:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: `${paths.src}/template/pages/main.pug`,
 filename: 'main.html'
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: `${paths.src}/template/pages/page.a.pug`,
 filename: 'page.a.html'
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: `${paths.src}/template/pages/page.b.pug`,
 filename: 'page.b.html'
})
```

**How to** make files *vendor~page.a.js* and *vendor~page.b.js* being added only to page.a.html and page.b.html respectively? And vendor~main.js being added to all three?

Like this:

**main.html**

- vendor~main.js
- main.js

**page.a.html**

- vendor~main.js
- vendor~page.a.js
- page.a.js
- main.js

**page.b.html**

- vendor~main.js
- vendor~page.b.js
- page.b.js
- main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest version of the HtmlWebpackPlugin (3.2.0) then consider upgrading it to beta version (4.0.0 -8) which support multiple entries. new version will automatically include chunks splitted by webpack.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: `${paths.src}/template/pages/main.pug`,
 filename: 'main.html',
 chunks: ['main']
}),
```

If upgrading to beta version is not an option then you have to create static vendor chunks and include all chunks in HtmlWebpackPlugin props:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
 template: `${paths.src}/template/pages/main.pug`,
 filename: 'main.html',
 chunks: ['main', 'vendor~main']
}),
```